# Change Sender of Outlook Item created from Template

Tags: vba, outlook

I am working with outlook files (.oft and .msg) that I want to send out using my account, even when the sender of the saved file is different.

```
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set send_account = EmailApp.Session.Accounts(1)    
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(template_path)
EmailItem.SendUsingAccount = send_account
EmailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = send_account.SmtpAddress
```

Even when using the SendUsingAccount and SentOnBehalfOfName methods, I still get the following message from my organisation:
*This message could not be sent. You do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user.*

Why does it not change the sender of the Email?

Comment: @eugene please stop adding [office-automation] to [vba] questions.   The tag wiki is quite clear "If you have a specific programming question about Excel or Word (or any other product from the MS Office package) and it is not about automating it via external software then use tags like excel, ms-word, vba, etc."

Comment: What is the difference when you automate any Office application from an external application or any other Office application?

Answer (score 1):

There is *no need to set up two properties* (`SendUsingAccount` and `SentOnBehalfOfName`) at the same time. They are entirely not related to each other.

> This message could not be sent. You do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user.

Seems like you don't have permissions to send on behalf of another person in Exchange. When you set up the `SentOnBehalfOfName` property you need to make sure that administrator set up the required privileges correctly. And also that property makes sense only if you deal with Exchange accounts in Outlook.

You need to use the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. Be aware, that account must be configured in Outlook. For example:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
     Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
     Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
     Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
     oMail.Send 
   End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that script before however, EmailApp.Session.Accounts.Count is 1 and EmailApp.Session.Accounts(1) = olPop3 is False, so the used outlook acccount does not correspond to a POP3 account.

Comment: You need to configure the second account under which you want to send emails or just set up privileges on the Exchange side to send emails on another persons.

Answer (score 1):

It means your template was created from a sent or received (rather than draft) message with the sender properties already set. You can either recreate the template or wipe out sender properties in the template.

Resetting `SendUsingAccount` or `SentOnBehalfOfName` properties won't help you. You need to either set the new `PR_SENDER_xyz` and `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_xyz` properties or delete the old ones.

I don't think these properties can be deleted using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperty / DeleteProperties`, but you can try to do that in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - open the template using "OutlookSpy|More functions|OpenIMsgOnIStg", select all `PR_SENDER_xyz` and `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_xyz` properties, click "Delete Properties".